# Reduce a time stamp to its date

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I am trying to compare current date with report date. The report date comes in this format: "2022-05-30 00:00:00.000000", whereas the current date I want to be in YYYY-MM-DD.

How can I either change the format, or strip the clock time from the timestamp?

```
var moment = require('moment');
var currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")

const jsonData = pm.response.json();
let date = (jsonData['data'][0]['date'])

pm.test("Fresh data is available", function () {
    pm.expect(date).to.eql(currentDate);
});
```

Comment: `"2022-05-30 00:00:00.000000".split(" ")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

As the datatype of the Date is string so you can use `.substring()` to extract only the portion you want. And in case of date, you want first 10 characters, i.e.,'`2022-05-30`' instead of '`2022-05-30 00:00:00.000000`'.

So you can use : `jsonData.data[0].date.substring(0,10)`